# Two services cannot have same name. A service with the wso2carbon-sts [null] name already exists in the system

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to install API Manager 1.6.0 on wso2esb 4.8.1. I have installed the selected features on this and while trying to restart,i am  getting the following exception...

```
`[2014-03-25 09:16:52,021] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.utils.deployment.Axis2ServiceRegistry} -  Error building service from bundle : Symbolic Name: org.wso2.carbon.sts,Bundle Version: 4.2.0, ID: 545
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Two services cannot have same name.  A service with the wso2carbon-sts [null] name already exists in the system.
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.addToAllServicesMap(AxisConfiguration.java:510)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisServiceGroup.addService(AxisServiceGroup.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.fillServiceGroup(DeploymentEngine.java:745)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.addServiceGroup(DeploymentEngine.java:601)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.deployment.Axis2ServiceRegistry.addServices(Axis2ServiceRegistry.java:218)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.deployment.Axis2ServiceRegistry.register(Axis2ServiceRegistry.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.deployment.Axis2ServiceRegistry.register(Axis2ServiceRegistry.java:89)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:473)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)`
```

Can anyone please help me on this..

I want to use both API manager and wso2 esb features simultaneosuly..So what is the best practice to do this? Is it possible to install the both in wso2 carbon??

I have tried a lot,not getting correct response from anywhere,,,please help me on this..

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to run WSO2ESB and API Manager separately.

Yes, it is possible to install both in WSO2 Carbon.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. But while installing the both in wso2carbon,i am facing the issue.. How to install both in wso2carbon..Can you help me on this please,,,i want to use both

Comment: How to install these two in carbon.I am using wso2carbon 4.2.0 which one need to install first ESB or API manager,Since i am new to wso2,can you help me on this pls

Comment: Did you try the Feature installation UI. Features has been grouped.      Please try the following link:    https://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Installing+Features+via+the+UI

Answer (score 0):

The ESB mediation engine is already part of API Manager. For example, you should be able to deploy a proxy service in API manager without any issue by copying the relevant proxy service artifact into file system. 
Can you please explain what type of ESB features are required to use with AM? Do you want to use the proxy service/sequence editor UI?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the Response,, I want to install fresh ESB (all the features ) on wso2 carbon and need to install API manager too.. Is it possible to do like this,,,